# Is it a good approach to run a script for 7 hrs?

Tags: selenium

Need suggestions
In my script, I have to check the status from the db and if the status is true I have to proceed with my execution, status will take 1 to 7 hours to populate as true.

My approach, every half an hour( or 15min) I will hit the db and get the status and verify it, if the status is false after 7 hrs then fail the test script.
In my code, I added a for loop which will run 14 times and inside I added 30 mins of sleep time and status validation condition, once the status becomes true break the loop.
Please let me know is it a good approach to run a script for 7 hrs??
Is there any alternative approach please suggests??

In QA env we change the status manually and proceed with the execution, but in Production env we can't change the status manually.

We are using selenium with java,testng framework, Maven project.
To connect to the db, I am using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many other ways of doing this. Example:

- Create a jenkins job that runs every 15 or 30 minutes to check the DB status and run selenium script.
- Create a windows batch file, which can execute your script. This batch file can also be scheduled to run every 15/30 mins using windows task scheduler

Both these methods (there would be more) would allow you to avoid running the script for 7 hours.

Comment: Thanks Anish, batch file u mean ".bat" file which will have the command to trigger the script?? How to know, suppose in the 2nd run it got the status as true from the db, so the next scheduled job should not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run any scripts for this amount of time, use jenkins to run a simple script that:

- checks the status of the DB
- if status == READY run the script, else do nothing

And schedule this to run every 1h or so every day but add a condition that if for example scripts were run this day, dont run this jenkins script today anymore.